# How do I save multiple objects to localStorage?

Tags: forms, object, local-storage

I am creating an online journal log. I am using a form to gather the information needed for the log. I want to display the information from the form in the log and organize it by date of entry. I have converted the form data into an object and saved that object to local storage. The issue is that I want to save multiple objects to local storage and store them in an array. I then want to take that info from local storage and display it in the log. Every time I submit a new form it gives me a new object instead of multiple objects over the course of a few days. I figured that out after I tried to push the object to an array and it would only push 1 object. Is this fixable?

```
const saveInputsToLocalStorage = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(event.target);
  const formDataObj = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());
  let formDataArray = [];
  formDataArray.push(formDataObj);

if (localStorage) {
    localStorage.setItem('formData', JSON.stringify(formDataObj));
  }

}
form.addEventListener('submit', saveInputsToLocalStorage);
```

I tried to search for some solutions on google but I don’t think they answered the question that I was trying to ask.